# Ubuntu 18.04 UK Macintosh keyboard problem

Tags: keyboard, 18.04, mac

I'm trying to apply the English (UK, Macintosh) input source on my physical [Keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAkYz.png) but no luck, I'm still getting ` and ~ on the top left button and < and > on the key next to the left shift.
What's interesting is that even gkbd-keyboard-display does not want to start, perhaps the layout have been messed up/have some bug?